# How to implement a Coming Soon page for my website without the users getting access to the main page?

Tags: html, publish

I'm working on my website using HTML, CSS, and JS only (no frameworks). In the meantime, I would like to create a coming soon page (without a timer) that will be displayed to the users once they click the URL to my website. How do I accomplish this task?

Comment: Just publish the coming soon page? don't include other pages.

Comment: okay, this might sound very silly but how exactly do I do that? I've only just started learning web dev a few months ago. Can you provide me with a link or anything that can help me? Thanks again.

Comment: Change your coming soon page name to index.html and keep it in root directory.

Comment: @JayNewbie, websites are just files, the browsers role is to read a folder and interpret the files inside as a website. If you don't want others to see the other pages then don't include the files for those when you deploy your website.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now. So for now I just include my coming soon page, but later on, when the website is complete, I can include all those files on the internet and simply remove the coming soon one then. Am I right?

Comment: What is your host ? CPanel ?

Comment: Host is goDaddy